# Kubernetes : Replication Controller still there after deletion

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl

I manage a K8s-cluster, managed by terraform :

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:17:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:05:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I want to delete a stack; so I removed the code and I applied. It throwed an error due to a timeout. I retried and I went successfully.

but now, I still have 2 replications controller (that are empty) :

```
portal-api                                          0         0         0         2h
portal-app                                          0         0         0         2h
```

no more service, no more horizontal_pod_scheduler; but still my replication_controller.

I tried to remove them :

```
$ kubectl delete rc portal-api                                                                                                      
error: timed out waiting for "portal-api" to be synced
```

Same if I want to force the deletion :

```
$ kubectl delete rc portal-api --cascade=false --force=true
$ 
$ kubectl get rc
[...]
portal-api                                          0         0         0         2h
portal-app                                          0         0         0         2h
[...]
```

I also still can see its configuration (filled with a `deletionTimestamp`) :

```
$ kubectl edit rc portal-api

# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-12-05T14:00:15Z
  deletionGracePeriodSeconds: 0
  deletionTimestamp: 2018-12-05T15:22:00Z
  finalizers:
  - orphan
  generation: 3
  labels:
    App: portal-api
  name: portal-api
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "32590661"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/replicationcontrollers/portal-api
  uid: 171f605e-f896-11e8-b761-02d4b8553a0e
spec:
  replicas: 0
  selector:
    App: portal-api
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        App: portal-api
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: false
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: AUTHORITY_MGR
          value: http://system-authority-manager-service
        image: gitlab.********************:4567/apps/portal/api:prd
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: portal-api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3300
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 256Mi
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    status:
  replicas: 0
```

Could someone help me on this ? Any idea ?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `kubectl edit rc portal-api` remove `finalizer` part from the resource:

```
finalizers:
  - orphan
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Could you explain a little bit more ? It seems I have similar issues with other resources... I'm investigating…

Answer (score 1):

This is about [Garbage Collection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/) and how to delete certain objects that once had an owner, but no longer have one.

> When you delete an object, you can specify whether the object’s dependents are also deleted automatically. Deleting dependents automatically is called  *cascading deletion*. There are two modes of  *cascading deletion*:  *background*  and  *foreground*.
>
> If you delete an object without deleting its dependents automatically, the dependents are said to be  *orphaned*.

You can read the documentation regarding [Controlling how the garbage collector deletes dependents](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/#controlling-how-the-garbage-collector-deletes-dependents), how does the Foreground cascading deletion and Background cascading deletion works.

> #### Setting the cascading deletion policy
>
> To control the cascading deletion policy, set the  `propagationPolicy`  field on the  `deleteOptions`  argument when deleting an Object. Possible values include “Orphan”, “Foreground”, or “Background”.
>
> Prior to Kubernetes 1.9, the default garbage collection policy for many controller resources was  `orphan`. This included ReplicationController, ReplicaSet, StatefulSet, DaemonSet, and Deployment. For kinds in the  `extensions/v1beta1`,  `apps/v1beta1`, and  `apps/v1beta2`  group versions, unless you specify otherwise, dependent objects are orphaned by default. In Kubernetes 1.9, for all kinds in the  `apps/v1`  group version, dependent objects are deleted by default
>
> kubectl also supports cascading deletion. To delete dependents automatically using kubectl, set  `--cascade`  to true. To orphan dependents, set  `--cascade`  to false. The default value for  `--cascade`  is true.
>
> Here’s an example that orphans the dependents of a ReplicaSet:
>   `kubectl delete replicaset my-repset --cascade=false`